# Retrieve domain instance by generated id

Tags: grails, identity, grails-domain-class

I am using a Domain class with a generated identity:

```
class User {
   ...
   static mapping = {
      id generator: 'assigned', name: 'uid'
   }

   Long uid
   ...
}
```

but when I try to retrieve an instance using

```
User.get(1)
```

it returns null. It does work if I use

```
User.findByUid(uid)
```

Is it not possible to use Domain.get or Domain.read when ids are generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your id is assigned, there's no need to declare the attribute.

```
class User {
  static mapping = {
    id generator: 'assigned' column: 'uid'
  }
}
```

The key here is to map the column name in the database.

Comment: This made it work. Thanks
I had to make "id bindable: true" to assing id in constructor, too.

Comment: True, by default the id excluded in the databinding, that's why you need bindable:true.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sergio's answer

The `generator` strategy is `assigned` which means application has to `assign` an id while saving the object. If you have done something like this below then you should be able to get `User.get(1)` otherwise an exception is thrown while saving without assigning an `id`

`def user = new User(id: 1).save(flush: true)`

Comment: As I commented on Sergio's answer, id wasn't being assigned in constructor, so I had to add:
id bindable: true

Comment: I was doing this but id wasn't being assigned. I had to add id bindable: true to the domain constraints to make this work.

Comment: I agree. I apologize I actually wanted to mean `user.id = 1` and then `user.save(flush: true)`. Was carried away with the notion of one liners. :)